# Discrete Fourier transorm vs Discrete Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

I am confused how the two related. They seem to be very related but I can't make a clear connection. Moreover, I can't make a connection for the case of I have a non-periodic function. What if one just takes a simple function, $f=x^2$, how do I start approaching DFT and DFS for this function?

Comment: the discrete Fourier transform is an unitary matrix $\mathbb{C}^N \to \mathbb{C}^N$, the Fourier series is an unitary transformation $L^2([0,T]) \to l^2(\mathbb{Z})$, the discrete time Fourier transform being the inverse transformation $l^2(\mathbb{Z}) \to L^2([0,1])$. You can think to the Fourier series as the limiting case of the DFT when $N \to \infty$, and the Fourier transform (an unitary transformaiton $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$) as the limiting case of the Fourier series when $T \to\infty$. For unifying all this, you need the Fourier transform of the (tempered) distributions.